# .net core default value when saving but identity info is different dbcontext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

On all my database tables i want to store the userid in a field called CreatedBy. I have a property on a base entity class for this.
My db context class currently looks like this:

```
namespace Infrastructure.Data
{
    public class ManagementContext : DbContext
    {
        public ManagementContext(DbContextOptions<ManagementContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Department> Department { get; set; }        

        public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSucess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            var AddedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(E => E.State == EntityState.Added).ToList();

            AddedEntities.ForEach(E =>
            {
                E.Property("CreatedOn").CurrentValue = DateTime.UtcNow;
              //E.Property("CreatedBy").CurrentValue = ????
            });

            var EditedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(E => E.State == EntityState.Modified).ToList();
            EditedEntities.ForEach(E =>
            {
                E.Property("LastModifiedOn").CurrentValue = DateTime.UtcNow;
            });
            return base.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSucess, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}
```

My identity user / info  is in a different context (as seen in the ewebshop demo)
How would i go about setting the value of CreatedBy? Should this be done elsewhere?

Comment: Does the CreatedBy property gets its value from the current connected user?

Comment: Yes it will be from the currently logged in user that has been authenticated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on the comment on your post, the `CreatedBy` column value always gets its value from the connected user so you need to do these steps:

Firstly, you need to configure the DI about how to get the current connected user like below into your `ConfigureServices` of `Startup` class:

```
services.AddScoped<IPrincipal>(
    provider => provider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.User);
```

Secondly, inject an instance of `IPrincipal` into your `DbContext` like below:

```
public ManagementContext(DbContextOptions<ManagementContext> options, IPrincipal principal)
    : base(options)
{
    this.principal = principal;
}
```

Finally when setting the value of `CreatedBy` column you get the current user by finding it from the value of `this.principal.Identity.Name`.

Comment: You may want to guard against a null value here.  This only works when there is an `HttpContext.User`.

Comment: @Brad `HttpContext.User`  is never `null` even when user is not connected. The only thing to care about is `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`

Comment: @CodeNotFound It's null when there's no `HttpContext`.  For instance, during Startup?

Comment: Your use case is not valid here. Explain me a real use case where I need to do use the DbContext in the Startup class and need to create data at the time ? Even if You do that the data you create on that time can use à IPrincipal You created yourself.

Comment: What if i want the logged in user's Id and not the name though, i guess i could have custom service that uses the usermanager to find the user object by the name. I'll try that.

Comment: @MikeB you can do that. But avoid using UserManager inside your DbContext because you will introduce circular referencing between two types. I will just query the User table through Users DBSete and get  the user id.

Comment: @CodeNotFound If you want to run migrations before the application starts or seeding data are two real use cases.  Sure you can manually create the DbContext but it doesn't make my statement invalid.  Your answer will throw NullReferenceException when there is no HttpContext when resolving the DbContext via the service provider.

Comment: @Brad Even for seed data etc you can say EF Core how You need your DbContext to be created Like I said in my previous comment you create a custom IPrincipal there.

Comment: For those who keep down voting. I really love you all ;-)